# Rackspace Pricing API

Tags: rackspace-cloud

I would like to show rackspace pricing on my website, is there any API available to get rackspace pricing, say for Compute Service. I have seen the calculator on website, but I want to capture all pricing details covering region and services?

Answer (score 4):

I work at Rackspace and we do not offer this API at the moment. You're welcome to vote for this feature at [Add price information to API for all services](https://feedback.rackspace.com/forums/250746-cloud-hosting/suggestions/5982228-add-price-information-to-api-for-all-services)

Comment: Thanks Matt, that will be greatly appreciated, this will in turn also help rackspace to publish pricing on different portals.

Comment: This suggestion is definitely under-advertised! That feature would be really awesome, especially when you use a lot of Rackspace infrastructure!